# Displayed "onto" a monitor or "on" a monitor?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Would it be correct to say 
**"Text is being displayed onto my computer screen"** or 
**"on my computer screen"**?

This is more of a technical question than purely grammatical. I would argue that nothing is being displayed "onto" a monitor as it is a grid of lights that emits an image, and the image is "on" the screen but not "onto".

I would think that it would be "onto" if there were something like a projector, where light is being shone "onto" a wall or screen and is then bouncing into or eyes.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Very good question unless it has typos. Can you read it through again and fix them?

Comment: My thighs are the top bits of my legs. ;-)

Comment: "On" is correct for your question and can usually be used in place of "onto" in the common cases that come to mind. By the way thighs connect my knees to my torso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, it's a technical problem with grammatical implications.

If the context is, for example, you have some sort of CPU architecture and you want to display some text to a prompt on a screen using serial communication, you could use "onto," as you are talking about the concept of moving data from your CPU memory to a recognizable form on the screen, however abstract the actual "movement" is.

If it's in your context, and you're debugging your pixel display with a test image, then you don't care about where the image was coming from, and whether it moved from anywhere. You probably just want to put an image "on" the screen.

"I drove my car onto the sidewalk." Alright, where from?

"I drove my car on the sidewalk." I don't care where from.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "on" and "onto" is that "onto" implies movement towards the position. Which you use in this case depends on whether you are conceiving of the display as essentially static or dynamic; which in my opinion is neither a technical nor a factual question, but purely one of how the speaker is choosing to frame the description.

Having said that, *on* is much more common than *onto* here: GlowBe has 9909 instances of "on a/the/every screen", against 434 of "onto a/the/every screen".